# I'm trying to use the optim package in octave latest mac version

Tags: octave

I Have a simple octave script

```
%!  ## Example for linear inequality constraints
%!  ## (see also the same example in 'demo nonlin_residmin')
%!
Ae = 1.5; ale = 0.1; omegae = 0.9 ; phie = 1.5;
noise = 0.1;
t = linspace(0,10,50); 
n = noise*randn(size(t));
function y = f(t,p)
    y = p(1)*exp(-p(2)*t).*cos(p(3)*t + p(4));
endfunction
y = f(t,[Ae,ale,omegae,phie])+ n;
plot(t,y,'+; data;')
% NOW try fit
A0 = 2; al0 = 0; omega0 = 1; phi0 = pi/2 ;
[fr,p] = leasqr(t,y,[A0,al0,omega0,phi0],'f',1e-10);
p 
yFit = f(t,p);
plot(t,y,'+',t,yFit)
legend ('data','fit')
```

But I get an error in the leasqr package
I have these packages installed

```
Package Name  | Version | Installation directory
--------------+---------+-----------------------
       optim  |   1.5.2 | /Users/Terence/octave/optim-1.5.2
      struct  |  1.0.15 | /Users/Terence/octave/struct-1.0.15
```

```
>> testNonlinearfit

error: '__plot_cmds__' undefined near line 296 column 3
error: called from
    leasqr at line 296 column 3
    testNonlinearfit at line 16 column 7
```

Any help  much appreciated

Comment: How have you installed which version of Octave? I think there are at least 6 ways to get GNU Octave on mac os. And apparently you haven't loaded the package (no * after the package name) so start your script with `pkg load optim`

Comment: Hi  It looks like I had an old version of optim it now works thanks for you help

Comment: I think you should delete this question in this case

Comment: you didn't answer my question but GNU Octave 4.4.0 is the latest stable build for Mac OS

Comment: Hi Thanks for all you comments I had an earlier version of the optic package and updating fixed that problem and I have found a dmg for vs 4.4 which also works and supports GUI call . Terry

Comment: Ah yes, we had email contact. I remember